# Trying to program a NI USB-6009 device in Python, but cannot fix the analogue ouput voltage because of error -200077

Tags: python, usb

I'm trying to program a [NI USB-6009](http://www.ni.com/de-de/support/model.usb-6009.html).
But I can't debug my code because of the error `-200077`.

This is my code:

```
Import nidaqmx
task=nidaqmx.Task()
task.ao_channels.add_ao_voltage_chan("Dev1/ao0")
task.write([5.0])
print task.read()
```